# Hash Join Showing up on Full Text Query - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing, full-text-search

I have the following Query in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT 
  PRODUCT_ID
FROM 
  PRODUCTS P
WHERE 
  SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_ID = 13225
  AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
  AND CONTAINS(*, 'FORMSOF(Inflectional, "%clip%") ')
```

What's interesting is that using this generates a Hash Match whereas if I use a different `SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_ID` (older supplier), it uses a Merge Join. Obviously the Hash is much slower than the Merge Join. What I don't get is why there is a difference, and what's needed to make it run faster?

FYI, there are about 5 million records in the PRODUCTS table. When supplier organization id is selected (13225), there are about 25000 products for that supplier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server - which version? Please add that info (as a tag, and maybe in the question itself).

Comment: SQL Server 2005.  Modifications to issue made.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for the question. I can't answer it for sure, but have you tried a DBCC DBREINDEX and an UPDATE STATISTICS on the table?

Comment: Trying that now....Tried Update Statistics, no help.  Trying dbcc dbreindex now.

Comment: DBCC REINDEX and UPDATE STATISTICS both ran...results still the same. :(

Comment: How much does performance differ between the two execution plans? How many records do belong to each SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_ID you try it with?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using the OPTIMIZE FOR Query Hint to force it one way or the other.

```
SELECT 
  PRODUCT_ID
FROM 
  PRODUCTS P
WHERE 
  SUPPLIER_ORGANIZATION_ID = @Supplier_Organisation_Id
  AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
  AND CONTAINS(*, 'FORMSOF(Inflectional, @Keywords) ')
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Supplier_Organisation_Id = 1000 ))
```

One other thing is your STATISTICS might out of date, the tipping point for automatic updates is often not low enough meaning that the query plan chosen may not be ideal for your data. I'd suggest trying updating the STATISTICS on your Products table, perhaps creating a job to do this on a regular basis if this is part of the problem.